# cleaner extension of elements using XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I defined xml schema the contains an element called 'field' and an extension to it called 'composite-field'.
it is defined as following:

```
<xs:complexType name="field">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>      
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="composite-Field">
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:extension base="field">
            <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="length" type="xs:integer" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

in order to use it in my XML ut has to be:

```
<field xsi:type="composite-Field">
  <value>enjoy</value>
  <length>30</length>
</field>
```

I don't want my XML users to use schema syntax such as **xsi:type=..." "** 
**Therefore my question is:** Is there any way to make the syntax of the XML be:

```
<composite-Field>
      <value>enjoy</value>
      <length>30</length>
</composite-Field>
```

so the name of the element will imply its inheritence and wouldn't force the users add type attribute **??** 
I tried this:

```
<xs:element name="MyCompositeField" type="composite-field"/>
```

and then:

```
<MyCompositeField>
          <value>enjoy</value>
          <length>30</length>
</MyCompositeField>
```

but it also didn't pass the XSD schema validation

---

**12/09/2010:** In response the suggested answer I refined my question a liitle bit. 
The schema looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

    <xs:element name="general">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="field" type="field" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="field"> 
        <xs:sequence> 
            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" /> 
        </xs:sequence> 
    </xs:complexType> 



    <xs:complexType name="composite-Field" > 
        <xs:complexContent> 
            <xs:extension base="field" > 
                <xs:sequence> 
                    <xs:element name="length" type="xs:integer" /> 
                </xs:sequence> 
            </xs:extension> 
        </xs:complexContent> 
    </xs:complexType> 

    <xs:element name="MyCompositeField" type="composite-Field"/> 

</xs:schema>
```

and the required xml looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <general xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema2.xsd">
    <MyCompositeField> 
        <value>enjoy</value> 
        <length>30</length> 
    </MyCompositeField> 

 </general>
```

using this combination I get in response the error message:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid
>   content was found starting with
>   element 'MyCompositeField'. One of
>   '{field}' is expected.

Comment: What's the context? Where and how are you using the schema?

Comment: I edited my answer to address your comment. Sorry for the long wait, I have been offline.

Comment: Your edit revealed a new problem so I've now updated my answer again.

Comment: I have another update for you since you redefined your problem

Answer (score 1):

Your question update shows that the real problem is in the `<general>` element. A valid document would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<general xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema2.xsd">
    <field> 
        <value>enjoy</value> 
    </field> 
</general>
```

Extending the type "field" does not modify the original type. Instead it creates a new type that is based on the old "field" type. If you wanted to have both `<value>` and `<length>` elements as the chlidren of `<field>` element, you should change the type of the `<field>` element from "field" to "composite-Field".

```
<xs:element name="general">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="field" type="composite-Field" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This validates document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<general xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema2.xsd">
    <field> 
        <value>enjoy</value> 
        <length>30</length> 
    </field> 
</general>
```

Other solution would be to change the `<general>` element have child element `<MyCompositeField>` instead of element `<field>` since `<MyCompositeField>` already has content type "composite-Field"

```
<xs:element name="general">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="MyCompositeField" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

which would validate document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<general xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema2.xsd">
    <MyCompositeField>
        <value>enjoy</value>
        <length>30</length>
    </MyCompositeField>
</general>
```

### Update 2010-08-14

Comment by original poster:

> But I want 'general' element to have the ability to contain either 'field' or 'composite-field'. Not to strict it to have ONLY one of those types.

So is your real problem is that you want your schema to validate both of these documents?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<general xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema2.xsd">
    <field> 
        <value>enjoy</value> 
    </field> 
</general>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<general xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema2.xsd">
    <MyCompositeField>
        <value>enjoy</value>
        <length>30</length>
    </MyCompositeField>
</general>
```

In that case the whole question can be seen as:

1. "how to allow an element to have one of these choices as a child element?"
   or because your types are almost similar:
2. "how to allow an optional element (element that can be absent)?"

The whole question could have been solved much faster if you had initially clearly stated what is your goal/code that you want to achieve and what code do you currently have that causes your problems

**Answer to #1** Use `<xs:choice>` to allow one of several independent child contents.

With this structure you can allow `<general>` to have either `<field>` or `<MyCompositeField>` child element

```
<xs:element name="general">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="field" type="field" />
            <xs:element name="MyCompositeField" type="composite-Field" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So this change in your schema would allow both of the documents I posted above.

**Answer to #2** If the only reason to have type `composite-Field` is to allow an optional `<length>` element you could just easily modify the original `field` type and use it instead of type `composite-Field`

```
<xs:complexType name="field"> 
    <xs:sequence> 
        <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" /> 
        <xs:element name="length" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" /> 
    </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>
```

This schema definition creates a type that allows an optional length element and thus validates both of these documents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<general xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema2.xsd">
    <field> 
        <value>enjoy</value> 
    </field> 
</general>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<general xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema2.xsd">
    <field> 
        <value>enjoy</value> 
        <length>30</length> 
    </field> 
</general>
```

Comment: no, this is not the solution. Change the type="composite-field" to "composite-Field" and still you won't be able to use this element in the xml. When trying I got the error message: "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'composite-Field'. One of '{field}' is expected".

Comment: Hi jasso, I saw your answer and edited my question so you could reproduce the problem that I raised. Thanks ahead...

Comment: But I want 'general' element to have the ability to contain either 'field' or 'composite-field'. Not to strict it to have ONLY one of those types. That is the point of extending an element.